# Scrapy with Python 2.7 on wsl/Red Hat, errors all the way

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler, typeerror

So I need to run Scrapy at work. I cannot use python3 for the moment because the installation is messed up (long story).

I install scrapy using `pip install scrapy`.
The version with `scrapy --version` is `1.8.3` and it's installed under python2.7 modules (I checked).

I can successfully run `scrapy startproject checktests` and `scrapy genspider example example.com`, as suggested by scrapy.

However, when I do `scrapy crawl example`, I first get an error in `queue.py` of queuelib:

```
File "/home/synthwave09/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/queue.py", line 7, in <module>
    from contextlib import suppress
ImportError: cannot import name suppress
```

I did a naive thing and rewrote a line using `suppress` in `queue.py`, so it's no longer using `contextLib suppress`(which requires python 3.4).

Now I am getting this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

QUESTION: what am I doing wrong and how can I make scrapy run with python 2.7?

Comment: How it is possible? On [scrapy 1.8.3. requirements.txt](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.8.3/requirements-py2.txt) we have `queuelib>=1.4.2,<1.6.0` version restrictions for queuelib. Code line `from contextlib import suppress` appeared only from queuelib v.1.6.0 [proof_link](https://github.com/scrapy/queuelib/blob/v1.6.0/queuelib/queue.py) which is restricted version as it doesn't match requirements for scrapy 1.8.3.

Comment: @Georgiy It seems that it's python itself and not scrapy that complains about queueLib. But that's not the only issue. I am note sure `1.8.3` is the right version for python 2.7. I trued with scrapy `1.2.3` and there were errors too. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.